# Tire for both road and wheel on turbo trainer use?

Tags: tire, turbo-trainer

I'm looking for a rear tire for use both on the road and on a wheel-on turbo trainer.

I'm currently using a fairly cheap road tire, but I'm finding it slips at higher resistances. I don't want to buy a second rear wheel and cassette, and I want to be able to go out on the road and train indoors without swapping tires.

I gather that turbo trainer specific tires are not safe for road use. What characteristics should I look for in a tire, that would make it suitable for turbo trainer use, in particular to reduce slippage, but still be safe on the road?

My bike is a conventional road bike, with modest tire clearance: it currently has 28mm tires on and probably wouldn't accommodate much wider.

Thanks

Comment: I would say that mainly you want a smooth section in the middle of the tread.  Many touring tires fit this description.

Comment: Check the surface of your trainer where it touches the tyre - if its polished smooth, a light scuff with sandpaper might be all you need.

Comment: You might also try lowering the tire pressure a bit to increase the contact patch.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. The tire I have is smooth in the middle section where it contacts the trainer's roller. It is pretty smooth and I could try roughen it up with sandpiper. Also I do have it pumped up fairly hard - I'll try dropping the pressure.